# Json load. Ошибка. Строка должна быть int

Tags: python, json, вконтакте

Есть json c vk https://github.com/Joffrey-ops/Joffrey/blob/main/photos.json

```
def get_largest(size_dict):
    if size_dict['width'] > size_dict['height']:
        return size_dict['width']
    else:
        return size_dict['height']

def main():
#здесь получили JSON используя vk api
    photos = json.load(open('photos.json'))['response']
    for photo in photos:
        sizes = photo['sizes']
        max_size = max(sizes,key=get_largest)
        print(max_size)

       
        # for size in sizes:
        #     print(size['type'])
        # print('_____________________________')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Выдает ошибку: TypeError: string indices must be integers.
Пробовал различные варианты исправить ошибку, не помогло. А конечный рез кода: достать только фотки большого разрешения следуя логике выше. Они там. Достать их можно, ссылки в JSON работают, только надо следовать другой логике.

***В конечном итоге, вот что получилось:данные из JSON*:**

```
    import requests
    import json
    
    
    def get_largest(size_dict):
        if size_dict['width'] >= size_dict['height']:
            return size_dict['width']
        else:
            return size_dict['height']
    
    
    def download_photos(url):
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        filename = url.split('/')[-1]
        filename2 = filename.split('?')[-2]
        # print(filename2)
        with open(filename2, 'wb') as file:
             for chunk in r.iter_content(4096):
                 file.write(chunk)
        # write_json(r.json())
    
    def main():
        photos = json.load(open('photos.json'))['response'].get('items')
        for photo in photos:
            sizes = photo['sizes']
            max_size_url = max(sizes,key=get_largest)['url']
            download_photos(max_size_url)
    
    
    
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`photos = json.load(open('photos.json'))['response']['items']`

Comment: Можно и просто `['items']`, зачем `get`? )

Comment: @CrazyElf на автомате сделал) Ответ подправил

Comment: В конечном итоге, все срослось, так или иначе, благодарю.